# Retrive last 1 week records on per day basis

Tags: mysql, date

I have created a table `emp_info` with email,mobile, timestamp as fields.

I want to retrieve last 1 week record on per day basis. And for this I have tried

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `emp_info` 
WHERE DATE(timestamp ) > DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
ORDER BY saved_timestamp
```

and it shows **total no. of records** entered in last 7 days which is not my desired out put.

So I want the out put of records for 7 days like:

```
  Day          count
  Monday       2
  Tuesday      0
  ....         ..
  ....         ..
```

So somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the [`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) to your column list and aggregate.

```
SELECT DAYNAME(timestamp), COUNT(*)
FROM `emp_info` 
WHERE DATE(timestamp ) > DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(timestamp)
ORDER BY saved_timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks !! But I also want to show the **DAYNAME** on which no record is filled i.e count(*) is 0 . So how to do that?

Comment: You need to create a temp table and `JOIN` to that.

Comment: I am trying a lot to fix it by join query but not getting the result so kindly guide me.

Comment: @Sam Please create a new question

Comment: I have asked another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838228/retrive-records-using-join-query) regarding this. Kindly go through it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract the day of week from the date then use the count and group it by the day of the week and you can get the count to each of the day.

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DATE(timestamp)), count(*) FROM `emp_info` WHERE DATE(timestamp ) > DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) group by DAYOFWEEK(DATE(timestamp))
```

Comment: The `DATE()` is unnecessary. The `DAYOFWEEK` function will only display the numeric representation of the day.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure abbout that the DAYOFWEEK is good for timestamps too.