# Retrieve records using JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve data of last 1 week from `emp_info` table on per day basis.

So I have used :

```
SELECT DAYNAME(timestamp), COUNT(*) 
FROM `emp_info` 
WHERE DATE(timestamp ) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(timestamp);
```

According to the query I am getting result like:

```
Monday    5
Thursday  7
```

But I also want the **result** of weekday as **0** on which no record has been entered.

From suggestions I come to know about **JOIN** query. So I have tried to fix it but not getting any  solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you are getting is right because there are no records on a specific dayname. Since you want to get all daynames, you need to project complete set of day (*using UNION inside a SUBQUERY*) and join it with your existing query.

```
SELECT  a.day_name,
        COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) totalCount
FROM
        (
            SELECT 'Sunday' day_name, 1 ordby UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Monday' day_name, 2 ordby UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Tuesday' day_name, 3 ordby UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Wednesday' day_name, 4 ordby UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Thursday' day_name, 5 ordby UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Friday' day_name, 6 ordby UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Saturday' day_name, 7 ordby 
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DAYNAME(timestamp) day_name, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    `emp_info` 
            WHERE   DATE(timestamp ) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
            GROUP   BY DAYNAME(timestamp)
        ) b ON a.day_name = b.day_name
ORDER   BY a.ordby
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*simple example*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d813/1)

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.  However, is there a way to force fill "0"s for missing days if I use my previous query? I ask this because if I've to fetch this data for a month, my query's going to become an essay.