# Display One Record Per Week From Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have mysql table as follows:

```
|id  | subject | link | week_number
------------------------------------
| 1  | ABC     | link1 | week-1
| 2  | DEF     | link2 | week-2
| 3  | GHI     | link3 | week-3
------------------------------------
```

Now I want To show week-1 record to user for one week after login and from his registration date as initial date for week counting....

then in next week, week-1 and week-2 should be visible,

then in next week, week-1, week-2 and week-3 records should be visible.

I am completely blank...so didn't tried any code....

your help or guideline appreciated...

Comment: you should have a created_at column in your table and then when you run the cron job all the rows created after that date can be returned

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836109/retrive-last-1-week-records-on-per-day-basis

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar My above table will be uploaded at a time... Member registration date will be different for each member....

Comment: So, there is one registration_date field ,.

Comment: You want count with registration date or last login date ??

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar regi. date. e.g. my regi date is 06 oct 2017, I will see week-1 record till 13 oct 2017, week-1,week-2 from 13 oct to 20 oct...week-1,week-2,week-3 from 20 oct to 27 oct and so on....till membership expiry date. Registration date of other member may be different...say 08 oct...then he will see week-1 from 08 oct to 15 oct...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a registration date, just make your live easier and change the column `week_number` to `days_after_reg` - and the values to `7,14,21`

Then you just need to compare this number with the current offset:

```
SELECT * from linktable WHERE `days_after_reg` <= datediff(Now(), UserRegistrationDate)
```

Either insert the user date with a variable, or "join" the tables.
Note that the join has no join condition here, so don't forget to filter on user-id (or name or something).

```
SELECT l.subject, l.link from linktable l cross join 
users u WHERE `l.days_after_reg` <= datediff(Now(), u.registrationDate) 
and u.id=5
```